# how to makeinfo the gcc manual texinfo files?

Tags: linux, unix, emacs, gcc

I downloaded an archive with the gcc info manual from [an official page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). Extracting the archive leads to not a single .texi file, but a very complex directory structure when many many .texi files. I'm not sure how to actually convert these to a single .info file (so that I can install-info that into my emacs info directory /usr/share/info, I know how to do that).

It is completely non-obvious to me how to get a .info file from this directory with many many .texi files. From the top-level directory that got extracted, I went to gcc/doc and then found (among about 30 other texi files) a file called gcc.texi. Trying `makeinfo gcc.texi` made it complain that `gcc.texi:25: @include: could not find gcc-common.texi`, even though that file is in gcc/doc/include.

What is the command I'm supposed to be using to build this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple straightforward way to extract just the code you want and then run that independently of the `Makefile` (which is generated from `Makefile.in` when you run `./configure` etc to build the entire GCC package).  If you genuinely need to build locally, follow the package's standard build instructions.

In some more detail, [`Makefile.in`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/master/Makefile.in) contains the following snippets;

```
info: do-info

# Make sure makeinfo is built before we do a `make info', if we're
# in fact building texinfo.
do-info: maybe-all-texinfo

install-info: do-install-info dir.info
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    if [ -f dir.info ]; then \
      $(INSTALL_DATA) dir.info $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)/dir.info; \
    else true; fi
#...
.PHONY: all-texinfo maybe-all-texinfo
maybe-all-texinfo:
@if gcc-bootstrap
all-texinfo: stage_current
@endif gcc-bootstrap
@if texinfo
TARGET-texinfo=all
maybe-all-texinfo: all-texinfo
all-texinfo: configure-texinfo
    @: $(MAKE); $(unstage)
    @r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    $(HOST_EXPORTS)  \
    (cd $(HOST_SUBDIR)/texinfo && \
      $(MAKE) $(BASE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) $(EXTRA_HOST_FLAGS) $(STAGE1_FLAGS_TO_PASS)  \
        $(TARGET-texinfo))
@endif texinfo
#...
.PHONY: do-install-info
do-install-info:
    @: $(MAKE); $(unstage)
    @r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    $(MAKE) $(RECURSE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) install-info-host \
      install-info-target


.PHONY: install-info-host

install-info-host: maybe-install-info-bfd
install-info-host: maybe-install-info-opcodes
install-info-host: maybe-install-info-binutils
install-info-host: maybe-install-info-bison
```

The definition proceeds with a very long list of individual targets, and I didn't follow through to the end.

Answer (score 0):

OP here, here's a hack that solves the issue, at least for the 8.3.0 version of the standalone texinfo sources downloaded from the link in the OP:

**TLDR:**

Step 1: In the `docs` folder which contains `gcc.texi`, open the file `install.texi2html` using a text editor, and remove the final line that says `rm $DESTDIR/gcc-vers.texi`.

Step 2: run the script using `./install.texi2html

Step 3: run `makeinfo gcc.texi -P ./HTML -P ./include`

Step 4: read the manual using `info gcc.info`, or from emacs, do `C-u F1 i` then `path/to/gcc.info`

**Explanation:**

it appears the issue is that the standalone texinfo sources tarballs listed on the [gcc onlinedocs page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) do not contain any Makefiles. It appears that the gcc maintainers simply didn't worry too much about making the standalone info manuals easy to compile.

Here's a hack to get it to work (this worked for me for the gcc 8.3 texinfo sources):

First, go to `gcc/gcc/docs` from where we extracted the archive. We will see `gcc.texi`, a directory named `include`, and some other `.texi` files. If we tried to do `makeinfo gcc.texi` now, we will get many complaints about things like `gcc-common.texi` not found. Those missing files happen to be in the `include` directory, so we add that to the search path using the `-P` option:

```
makeinfo gcc.texi -P ./include
```

However, we will get a complaint about a missing `gcc-vers.info`. That file is nowhere to be found, but was intended to be generated automatically by `autogen` when the full gcc source tree (not just the texi sources) is configured and built. However, we are in luck, because in the same directory as `gcc.texi`, there's a script called `install.texi2html`. At the end of the script, we see the line:

```
rm $DESTDIR/gcc-vers.texi
```

This means that the script is actually generating the file we need, but then deleting it. Hence, simply remove that line from the script, run it again, and we'll see `HTML/gcc-vers.texi`. Then we can add the `HTML` directory to the path, and this time `gcc.texi` builds correctly.

By the way, most of the `.texi` files are actually subnodes. Fortunately, they are easily identified by a comment near the beginning of each file. To filter them out (by that comment) and see a list of toplevel node files, do

```
grep -L '@c This is part of the' *.texi
```

The resulting files are

```
ppinternals.texi
cpp.texi
gccint.texi
gcc.texi
install.texi
poly-int.texi
```